# Even after +500mb set in max_allowed_packet... it still gives me an error

Tags: mysql, drupal, caching

I´ve just moved my Drupal site to a new managed VPS.

Each time I try to run cron, I get this nasty error:

> Warning: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes query:
>   INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link,
>   location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (1, 'php', '%message in
>   %file on line %line.', 'a:4:{s:6:\"%error\";s:12:\"user
>   warning\";s:8:\"%message\";s:1582172:\"Got a packet bigger than
>   'max_allowed_packet' bytes\nquery: UPDATE cache_update SET
>   data =
>   'a:72:{s:10:\"admin_menu\";a:10:{s:5:\"title\";s:19:\"Administration
>   menu\";s:10:\"short_name\";s:10:\"admin_menu\";s:10:\"dc:creator\";s:3:\"sun\";s:11:\"api_version\";s:3:\"6.x\";s:17:\"recommended_major\";s:1:\"1\";s:16:\"supported_majors\";s:3:\"1,3\";s:13:\&qu
>   in /home/drupal/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 135

The thing is that I´ve set  max_allowed_packet to 64, then 100, then 250 and then 512!!!
And still gives me that error.

That error seems to be related to the admin_menu module, but even after disabling that module, the error is still there (referencing other module) and after disabling that other module, the error is still there, and so on an on.

It seems that the problem is related to the mySQL table "cache_update" but I can´t understand what´s going on. Even after searching Drupal forums, I couldn´t manage to get to the problem. Just found some ways hacking core, wich isn´t good.

I think this is a mysql specific issue, so that´s why I´m posting this here.

Thanks for your insight!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to consider:

1. Are you sure that the syntax of `max_allowed_packet` is correct? Are you specifying the units? i.e. `max_allowed_packet = 512M`
2. Are you sure MySQL is using the same `my.cnf` file you are editing? Login to MySQL from console, and run: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;` Is `max_allowed_packet` set correctly?
3. Finally, if all fails, consider this workaround via Drupal Tweaks module: http://drupal.org/project/drupal_tweaks

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! The guys at my hosting have change the values, so I´ve assumed they were using the correct syntaxis. Maybe I should go and verify that by myself...

Comment: I´ve checked with the root user, at phpmyadmin, and this is the configuration:
Variable  Session value / Global value
max allowed packet 1,048,576 
slave max allowed packet 1,073,741,824

Comment: I´ve checked using the console and it says the same: 
+--------------------+---------+
| Variable_name      | Value   |
+--------------------+---------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1048576 |
+--------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Perhaps the value may need to be even higher than that. For the sake of a test, are you able to push it up even higher? Of course, don't leave it super high in production.

Comment: The weird thing is that this is a production site and this error only appeared after a migration process to another VPS...